# C++ : generic getter/setter for each single member of private struct

Tags: c++, struct, private, member, getter-setter

Probably a common one, but can't find any existing topic here.

So I have a class with a private struct with many members. I want to write getters and setters for single members, but it would be long and repetitive to write one getter/setter for each member ... how to be generic easily ?

```
class C {

   public:
       typedef struct S {
             int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
       }S;
       void setS(S new_struct);
       S getS();
       void setSElement(????, int value);
       int  getSElement(????);
    private:
       S data;

}
```

What to replace the ????? with to directly refer to which element of S I want (a through h) ?

No need to say, I need the struct to remain a struct and not be mingled with my other class members, and I also need to be able to get/set the struct entirely at once.

Thanks in advance,

Charles

Comment: Maybe not always, but there usually is something wrong in the design if you want something like this.

Comment: Why `S` is private, if you provide getter/setter for this members throw `C` ?

Comment: Why not use an array instead, and so you provide index for `????`.

Comment: 1) Why private + get/set : Because lots of checks and conversions need to be done in the getters/setters (check value consistency, convert from degrees to radians, check unit consistency and perform other conversions when needed ...), but I don't want the user to worry about that

Comment: 2) Why not array : because I want S's members to have explicit names, they all have very different meanings and are not just similar elements in a sequence

Comment: Use std::tuple or std::array instead.

Comment: Which interface do you want ? then adapt internal to its interface.

Comment: You may have correct name interface, even with internal array: `int getA() const { return array[static_cast<int>(EIndex::A)]; }`

Comment: Interface desired : access either whole struct (with a struct getter/setter) or single members. This struct is a module configuration with multipel different parameters, not necessarily related. I need specific names here, not indexes of an array.

Comment: @Jarod42 Would you care to expand on your array and EIndex solution ? I don't seem to understand the first bit of it, I have never seen such a thing.

Comment: I could also use an enum with the same names as in the struct, with fixed values, and then use struct padding to figure my way around given an enum item. But that's ugly, to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea if your motivation is *but it would be long and repetitive to write one getter/setter for each member ...*.

It is useful for the user of `C`to have explicit names for each member. This is how almost all languages supporting OOP are designed. Maybe smalltalk being the exception.

You also mention you have to do validation for the setters. The `setSElement` function would quickly become complex.

If you want to keep type-safety for the function call You get even more code to accomplish that.

That being said, if you want a suggestion for what ???? could be, a simple enum would be fine.

```
class C{
  public:
     enum SElement{ a, b ...

     setSElement(SElement member, int value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstddef>

class C {
  public:
    typedef struct S {
      int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
    } S;

    inline void setSElement(std::size_t offset, int value) {
      *(int*)((C::S*)&data + offset) = value;
    }

    inline int getSElement(std::size_t offset) {
      return *(int*)((C::S*)&data + offset);
    }

  private:
    S data;
};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  C c;
  c.setSElement(offsetof(C::S, a), 20);
  printf("a = %d\n", c.getSElement(offsetof(C::S, a)));

  return 0;
}
```

Shorthand methods through macros:

```
#define SET_S(__e__) inline void setSElement_ ## __e__ (int value) { setSElement(offsetof(C::S, __e__), value); }
#define GET_S(__e__) inline int getSElement_ ## __e__ () { getSElement(offsetof(C::S, __e__)); }

    SET_S(a)
    GET_S(a)
```

Usage:

```
C c;
c.setSElement_a(30);
printf("a = %d\n", c.getSElement_a());
```

Answer (score 1):

To set specific data member of `S` with just one function
you can use such interface:

```
void setSElement(int S::*field, int val) {
    data.*field = val;
}
int getSElement(int S::*field) const {
    return data.*field;
}
```

and you can use it in such way:

```
C c;
c.setSElement(&C::S::a, 17);
c.setSElement(&C::S::b, 16);
std::cout << c.getSElement(&C::S::a) << "\n";
```

by the way in c++ you no need such C way combo: `typedef struct S {} S`, you can just write `struct S {}`.

Answer (score 1):

`enum` and `std::array` can be used like,

```
class C {
public:
    std::array<int, 3> Elems;
    enum class index {a, b, c};

    void setElements(const std::array<int, 3>& elems) { Elems = elems;}
    std::array<int, 3> getElements() const { return Elems;}

    void setElemAtIndex(index at, int value) { 
        Elems[static_cast<int>(at)] = value;
    }
    int getElemAtIndex(index at) const { 
        return Elems[static_cast<int>(at)];
    }       
};
```

and can be used like;

```
C obj;
obj.setElements(std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3});
auto elems = obj.getElements();

obj.setElemAtIndex(C::index::c, 30);
auto a = obj.getElemAtIndex(C::index::c);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements, it seems you want some enum:

```
class C {
   public:
       enum class EIndex {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H};
       struct S {
             int get(EIndex) const;
             int& get(EIndex);
             int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
       };
       void setS(const S& new_data) { data = new_data}
       const S& getS() const { return data; }
       void setSElement(EIndex index, int value) { data.get(index) = value; }
       int  getSElement(EIndex index) { return data.get(index); }
    private:
       S data;
}

int C::S::get(EIndex index) const
{
    const int array[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
    return array[static_cast<int>(index)];
}

int& C::S::get(EIndex index)
{
    int* array[] = {&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g, &h};
    return *array[static_cast<int>(index)];
}
```